# Advice on deploying services like NTP, DNS, Radius etc for a small NOC

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, ntp, syslog, radius

network engineer here. I recently deployed a small office network and was asked to help out with deployment of some of the services. I have two ESXi servers on my hands and I need to deploy NTP, Radius, Syslog and some management software. I would need a suggestion on how should I approach this and it would be a great aid if you could help me with the following:

1. I was wondering whether all of these services should be separated in their own virtual machines, containers or deployed altogether in a single VM?
2. In terms of redundancy should 2 VMs be deployed, one on each of the ESXi servers or just a single VM and use VMware HA that would fail over VM to the other ESXi server?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Brief answer sorry - use separate VMs where possible (less efficient but more flexible), try to use appliances if possible, use redundancy for services you need all the time (DNS perhaps, remember to use anti-affinity rules) and HA for when you can live with a short outage (NTP).

Comment: How many users do you have in the office?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Federi - as of right now just 5 people will be using this infrastructure on a day to day basis along with lots of networking equipment for proof of concept purposes and testing.